# pythonによる重み付きボロノイ図の描画

Tags: python

pythonベースのCOTSシミュレーションシステムを使って、マルチエージェントの
研究をしているものです。

ある領域に複数のエージェントを最適配置する際、個々のエージェントの座標から
voronoi領域を計算することがあります。

通常のボロノイ領域の計算やボロノイ図の描画でしたら、
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
を活用するのですが、各エージェントの能力に差がある場合、担当する領域を単に
幾何学的に分割するのではなく、各エージェントに応じて重み付けをした領域に分
割したいと考えております。

pythonで「加法的重み付きボロノイ図」や「乗法的重み付きボロノイ図」を描画す
るために、何か参考になる情報をお持ちでしたら是非ご教授願います。